# How to link Multiple radio buttons with multiple panel on same form in C#..

Tags: c#

Actually I want to make a calculator which consist of standard, scientific and programmer functionality each on different panel but on same  form how to control these panels with their corresponding radio buttons on the form..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon changing the radio button (there is an event for that) simply set the visibility of different panels and whatever widths are appropriate for the form.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have 3 RBs, `rb1, rb2, rb3` on the form and in the `groupBox`. And 3 user controls or panels with specific function.

```
// wire all buttons to same event
rb1.CheckedChanged += OnCheckChanged;
rb2.CheckedChanged += OnCheckChanged;
rb3.CheckedChanged += OnCheckChanged;

private void OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (rb.Checked)
    {
        if (rb.Name = "rb1")
            panel1.BringToFront();
        elseif (rb.Name = "rb2")
           panel2.BringToFront();
        else
           panel3.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

In this method we assume that all panels or controls are already on the form. You only need to change their z-Order. You also need to setup initial one in the `form.Load`, or in designer as well as corresponding button should be checked , for example

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel1.BringToFront(); 
}
```

This is only one of the few ways to of doing it. Hopefully ,this one is easy to understand